# Number shown incorrectly when grid is exported as Excel (xls file)

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Export Excel file shows for instance 1500 as 1?500.

This is specific to machines in particular country.

How should I go about fixing this region specific issue.

Comment: Do you have any code relating to this issue? Which particular country? Are random question marks the only incorrect occurences?

Comment: It happens for France. I don't have any code related to that right now. I tried to reproduce this at my end in india using below code but n could not :          // Sets the culture to French (France)
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            // Sets the UI culture to French (France)
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I was also thinking down that line. it may be caused by different keyboard formats. But is there any other way to fix it without going to replace the symbols and all..